# Find students studying two subjects with three different roles SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `students` with student **id**, **subjects** and **number of roles** per subject. How to find students who studied at least two subjects where they had exactly three roles?

```
student    subject    num_roles
1000       223        2
1000       223        1
-------------------------------
1043       243        3
-------------------------------
1002       109        3
1002       230        3
1002       200        1            valid student
...
```

I can only think of finding students and their subjects that are equal to `3` `num_roles`. But how to modify the code to find students with `3` roles in at least `2` subjects?

```
SELECT s.student, s.subject
FROM students s
WHERE s.num_roles = 3 
ORDER BY s.student, s.subject;
```

Expected output:

```
student     subject 
1002        109
1002        230
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Select student , subject 
  From students 
  where student in (
    Select student 
    From students 
    where num_roles = 3
    Group by student having count(subject) >1
  )
  and num_roles = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and fast with `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT student, subject
FROM   students s1
WHERE  num_roles = 3
AND    EXISTS (  -- same student has another subject with 3 roles
   SELECT FROM students s2
   WHERE  s2.num_roles = 3
   AND    s2.student = s1.student
   AND    s2.subject <> s1.subject
   )
ORDER  BY 1,2;
```

A multicolumn index on `(num_roles, student)` would be the optimum for this query. (Typically, it won't pay to append the `subject` to the index.)

A query using `GROUP BY` & `count()` is more expensive and has to use a sequential scan of the whole table, plus another index (or sequential) scan. Test with `EXPLAIN` / `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are satisfied with one row per student, you can use `array_agg()` to combine the subjects:

```
SELECT s.student, ARRAY_AGG(s.subject) as subjects
FROM students s
WHERE s.num_roles = 3 
ORDER BY s.student, s.subject
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```